# grep: Invalid regular expression

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, text-files

I have a text file which looks like this:

```
haha1,haha2,haha3,haha4
test1,test2,test3,test4,[offline],test5
letter1,letter2,letter3,letter4
output1,output2,[offline],output3,output4
check1,[core],check2
num1,num2,num3,num4
```

I need to exclude all those lines that have "[ ]" and output them to another file without all those lines that have "[ ]".

I'm currently using this command:

```
grep ",[" loaded.txt | wc -l > newloaded.txt
```

But it's giving me an error:

> grep: Invalid regular expression

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `grep -F` to treat the search pattern as a fixed string. You could also replace `wc -l` with `grep -c`.

```
grep -cF ",[" loaded.txt > newloaded.txt
```

If you're curious, `[` is a special character. If you don't use `-F` then you'll need to escape it with a backslash.

```
grep -c ",\[" loaded.txt > newloaded.txt
```

By the way, I'm not sure why you're using `wc -l` anyways...? From your problem description, it sounds like `grep -v` might be more appropriate. `-v` inverts grep's normal output, printing lines that *don't* match.

```
grep -vF ",[" loaded.txt > newloaded.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

**An alternative method to Grep**

It's unclear if you want to remove lines that might contain either bracket `[]`, or only the ones where the brackets specifically surround characters. Regardless of which method you intend to use, `sed` can easily remove lines that fit a definitive pattern:

To delete only lines that contained both brackets surrounding characters `[...]`:

```
sed '/\[.*\]/d' loaded.txt > newloaded.txt
```

Another approach might be to remove any line that contained  either bracket:

```
sed '/\[/d;/\]/d' loaded.txt > newloaded.txt
```

(eg. lines containing either `[` or `]` would be deleted)

Answer (score 0):

Your grep command doesn't seem to be excluding anything. Also, why are you using `wc`? I thought you want the lines, not their count.

So if you just want the lines, as you say, that don't have `[]`, then this should work:

```
grep -v "\[" loaded.txt > new.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `awk` for this:

```
awk -F\[ 'NF==1' file > newfile
cat newfile
haha1,haha2,haha3,haha4
letter1,letter2,letter3,letter4
num1,num2,num3,num4
```

Or this:

```
awk '!/\[/' file
```